# How to extract Angular.js form request to work independently?

Tags: angularjs

If there is a POST request form on a website which is working with Angular. How to extract independent POST request which can work via jQuery or PostMan etc and retrieve response.

If we have this running Angular site code:

```
<form ng-submit="submit(form)" name="$parent.accounts" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
   <!-- ngIf: status && status !== 200 -->
   <div class="row" ng-class="{'has-error': (accounts.username.$dirty &amp;&amp; accounts.username.$invalid)}">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
         <label for="login-username" class="control-label sr-only ng-binding">Username</label><input ng-model="form.username" type="text" class="form-control input-with-feedback ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-valid-sp-disallow-chars" name="username" id="login-username" placeholder="Username" required="" sp-disallow-chars=":%&amp;'`´&quot;" sp-disallow-chars-model="usernameDisallowedChars" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autofocus="autofocus" ng-trim="false"><!-- ngIf: accounts.username.$dirty && accounts.username.$invalid -->
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" ng-class="{'has-error': (accounts.password.$dirty &amp;&amp; accounts.password.$invalid)}">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
         <label for="login-password" class="control-label sr-only ng-binding">Password</label><input ng-model="form.password" type="password" class="form-control input-with-feedback ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" name="password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" required="" autocomplete="off" ng-trim="false"><!-- ngIf: accounts.password.$dirty && accounts.password.$invalid -->
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row row-submit">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
         <div class="checkbox"><label class="ng-binding"><input ng-model="form.remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="login-remember" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"> Remember me <span class="control-indicator"></span></label></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-green ng-binding">Log In</button></div>
   </div>
</form>
```

How can we get valid post request data, like keys, url, etc to make it work from postman forexample

Comment: The same way you used to implement the POST query with angular: by reading the documentation of the REST API (or by reading its code). Or by guessing it thanks to the request payload that you can see in the Network tab of the browser dev tools.

Comment: Most of that code is client-side validation - which you obviously can't replicate with PostMan. All you need to know is the form submit URL, and the form inputs that are sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Chrome, the requests that your browser sends can be examined in the `Network` tab of your developer tools. Most of other browsers have similar capabilities. The most portable way to open dev tools is probably right-clicking somewhere on the page and selecting `Inspect element`. That usually sends you to the `Elements` tab, and you can switch to `Network` from there.

This is what that panel looks like in Chrome on Windows:
[image: "Network" tab in Chrome developer tools]